# How do I detect Object's changes when saving it in Play!Framework?

Tags: playframework

I'm saving an `Organization` Object, I need to delete all its `OrgFieldValue` when someone changes its `OrgType`:

```
public static void save(@Valid Organization org) {

    Logger.info("" + org.orgType.id);
    Organization old = Organization.find("id = ?", org.id).first();
    Logger.info("" + old.orgType.id);

    if (old != null && old.orgType.id != org.orgType.id) {
        for (OrgFieldValue v : org.orgFieldValues) {
            v.delete();
        }
    }
    org.save();
    index();

}
```

The problem is, the `old.orgType.id` is always same as `org.orgType.id`, I mean, the `old`  object is automatically filled with new `ortType` id, that's pretty weird since I didn't save it yet.

Any help ?